# OverQuotaError on datastore writes after 1.9.18 update when console shows quota OK

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-quotas

Has anyone seen this?

Nothing on my console shows over quota but my logs are showing errors and all of my methods are failing. I have never hit quota and we are still in DEV and have no active users. Today was a light day for us in testing.

Error:

Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: OverQuotaError (The API call datastore_v3.Put() required more quota than is available.)

I cannot post images because I do not have enough rep points, but every datastore related quota is "Okay".

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you are hitting one of these Limits (not Quotas) [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/#quotas